# Python combine items in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, combinations

Suppose

I have A dictionary A

```
A={'a':{0:[1,2,3],1:[4,5,6]},'b':{0:['u','v','w'],1:['x','y','z']}}
```

I want to combine all the elements in 'a' and 'b'

that

```
[[1,2,3,'u','v','w'],
 [1,2,3,'x','y','z'],
 [4,5,6,'u','v','w'],
 [4,5,6,'x','y','z']]
```

I have tried:

```
c=[]
for k,v in A.items():
    for i,t in v.items():
        c.append(t+t)
```

But it does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the `itertools` method outlined above by Ajax1234, you can do it with just list comprehensions:

Start with transforming your dict into a list of lists:

```
l_of_l = [list(i.values()) for i in A.values()]
```

Then combine each sublist with another list iteration:

```
result = [i+v for i in l_of_l[0] for v in l_of_l[1]]
```

giving you this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 'u', 'v', 'w'], [1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y', 'z'], [4, 5, 6, 'u', 'v', 'w'], [4, 5, 6, 'x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
A={'a':{0:[1,2,3],1:[4,5,6]},'b':{0:['u','v','w'],1:['x','y','z']}}
results = [[c for _, c in b.items()] for a, b in A.items() if a in ['a', 'b']]
last_results = [a+b for a, b in itertools.product(*results)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 'u', 'v', 'w'], [1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y', 'z'], [4, 5, 6, 'u', 'v', 'w'], [4, 5, 6, 'x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone wants to achieve this for more than two nested dictionaries:
The following code works in for those inputs as well:

```
import itertools

input = {'a':{0:[1,2,3],1:[4,5,6]},'b':{0:['u','v','w'], 1:['x','y','z']}}
list_of_lists = [list(x.values()) for x in input.values()]
res = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in itertools.product(*list_of_lists)]
print(res)
```