# Combine a dictionary item to a list of dictionaries in

Tags: python, dictionary

Hope you have a nice moment,

I got a problem on dictionaries.

Suppose we have a dictionary `A` with `n` keys (in this case, there are 2):

```
A = {
    weather: ['sunny', 'rain', 'cloudy'],   
    temperature: ['warm', 'cold']
}
```

We want to create a `list` of `dict` with each combinations of the items. Since in the example there are 3 item x 2 item so there will be a list with 6 dictionary.

The result will look like this:

```
B = [
    {weather: 'sunny', temperature='warm'},
    {weather: 'sunny', temperature='cold'},
    {weather: 'rain', temperature='warm'},
    {weather: 'rain', temperature='cold'},
    {weather: 'cloudy', temperature='warm'},
    {weather: 'cloudy', temperature='cold'}
    ]
```

What I currently try is:

```
B = []
for key,value  in A.items():
    for item in value:
        B.append([key, item])
```

But it fails.

Is there any way to accomplished this ? 
These are some important concerns:

- The keys are on the same level.
- The number of keys will be dynamically. So, the case 
  [Python combine items in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183510/python-combine-items-in-a-dictionary) won't work. (Maybe some modifications will)

Any solution will be grateful.
(Sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a short expression making use of `zip`, the `values` method, and `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> A = {'weather': ['sunny', 'rain', 'cloudy'], 'temperature': ['warm', 'cold']}
>>> B = [dict(zip(A, x)) for x in product(*A.values())]
>>> for d in B:
...   print(d)
...
{'weather': 'sunny', 'temperature': 'warm'}
{'weather': 'sunny', 'temperature': 'cold'}
{'weather': 'rain', 'temperature': 'warm'}
{'weather': 'rain', 'temperature': 'cold'}
{'weather': 'cloudy', 'temperature': 'warm'}
{'weather': 'cloudy', 'temperature': 'cold'}
```

The call to `product` creates a list of pairs like `('sunny', 'warm')`. When you zip such a pair with the `dict` keys, you get a sequence of pairs like `('weather','sunny')` and `('temperature','warm')`, which `dict` can turn into the desired dictionary.

Note that this works because the iterator that provides the keys and the `values` method both return their elements in the same order, so that you don't have to worry about getting something like `{'weather': 'warm', 'temperature': 'sunny'}`.

Comment: Hey, thank you man. This is the way I meant. Finally can generate the cartesian product. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```py
A = {
    'weather': ['sunny', 'rain', 'cloudy'],   
    'temperature': ['warm', 'cold']
}

B = [{'weather': a,'temperature': b} for a in A['weather'] for b in A['temperature']]
```

Could you try this !

Comment: nice one thanks, but it statically create a `for` loop for each keys.